# How do you bind double tap key in Oh My Zsh?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to bind double tab to "autosuggest-accept" from the auto suggest plugin:

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions

Having to press right arrow to accept suggestion is a bit cumbersome and just double tapping tab would make it so much faster.

Any ideas how to bind a double tap key in Oh My Zsh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```bsh
bindkey '\t\t' autosuggest-accept
```

However, this will make single <kbd>Tab</kbd> slower to react, because now, every time you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> the first time, the Zsh Line Editor will wait `$KEYTIMEOUT` milliseconds to see if a second <kbd>Tab</kbd> press is forthcoming, instead of reacting immediately.

You're probably better off binding it to something like <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> instead:

```bsh
bindkey '\e\t' autosuggest-accept
```

Or perhaps <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>:

```bsh
bindkey '\e ' autosuggest-accept
```

Or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```bsh
bindkey '\e\r' autosuggest-accept
```

`bindkey` documentation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle_002c-builtin-commands